# What does this error mean and can someone please provide the answer? It keeps saying Parser error on the burn function

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, erc-20, erc-223

[image: Click here]Click Here for the image. `

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; }

contract TheJEFF {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name;
    string public symbol; 
    uint8 public decimals = 3;
    uint256 public totalSupply; 

    // This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    //This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

    //This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     * 
     * Intializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     * */
     function TheJEFF(
         uint256intialSupply,
         string tokenName,
         string tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        totalSupply = intialSupply *50000000.000** uint256(3);
        balanceOf [msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        name = "TheJEFF";
        symbol = "GXAU";
    }

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        //Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to = 0x0);
        //Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        //Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf [_to]);
        //Check if sender is frozen
        require(!frozenAccount[_from]);
        //Check if recipient is frozen
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);
        //Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        //Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        //Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] -+ _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    /**
     * Destroy tokens
     * Remove value from the system irreversibly
     * 
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) 
    {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        emit Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}

uint256 public sellPrice;
uint256 public buyPrice;

mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

/* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

    /*Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function TheGoldmoneyToken(
    uint256 initialSupply, 
    string tokenName,
    string tokenSymbol
    ) TokenERC20(initialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol) public{}

    /* Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract */
    function _transfer(address _from, address_to, uint_value) internal {
        require (_to != 0x0);
        require (balanceOf[_from]>= _value);
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceof[_to]);
        require(!frozenAccount[_from]);             //Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);               //Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                 //Check for overflows
        balanceOf[_to] += -value;                   //Check if recipient is frozen
        emit Transfer (_from, _to, _value);         //Add the same to the recipient
    }

///Create 'mintedAmount' tokens and send it to 'target'
///@param target address to receive tokens
///@param mintedAmount the amount of tokens it will receive
function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner public {
    balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
    totalSupply += mintedAmount;
    emit Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
    emit Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
}

///@notice 'freeze?' Prevent| Allow 'target' from sending & receiving tokens
///@param target Address to be frozen
///@param freeze either to freeze it or not
function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner public {
    frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
    emit FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
}
//Allow token to automatically detect and refill user balance if balance is too low to pay for Ether blockchain transaction cost
uint public minBalanceForAccounts;

function setMinBalance(uint minimumBalanceInFinney) onlyOwner {
    minBalanceForAccounts = minimumBalanceInFinney * 10 finney;
}

/*Send coins*/
//If the sender does not meet minimum requirement, this allows them to be refunded
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
    if(msg.sender.balance < minBalanceForAccounts)
        sell((minBalanceForAccounts - msg.sender.balance)/ sellPrice);
}

///@notice Allow users to buy tokens for 'newBuyPrice' eth and sell tokens for 'newSellPrice' eth
///@param newSellPrice Price users can buy from the contract
///@param newBuyPrice Price users can buy from the contract
}

///@notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether///
function buy() payable public (uint amount) {
    uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;                 //calculates the amount
    _transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);                //makes the transfers
}

///@notice Sell 'amount' tokens to contract
///@param amount of tokens to be sold
function sell(uint256 amount) public {
    address myAddress = this;
    require(myAddress.balance >= amount * sellPrice)    //checks if contract has enough ether to buy
    _transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);                //makes the transfers
    msg.sender.transfer(amount * sellPrice);            //sends ether to the seller
}

///**ERC223 compatability features**
 contract ERC223 {  
     //Check if address we are sending token to is a contract//
    function transfer(address to, uint value, bytes data) {
        uint codeLength;
        assembly {
            codeLength := extcodesize(_to)        }
    }
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    if(codelength>0) {
        //Allows for tokens to not be lost in contract//
        ERC223ReceivingContract receiver = ERC223ReceivingContract(_to);
        receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);
    }



 }
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a bracket (`}`) missing:

change

```
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
    public
    returns (bool success) {
    tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
    if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
        return true;
    }
```

to

```
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
    public
    returns (bool success) {
    tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
    if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
        return true;
    }
}
```